# How to use the enum of one .proto file in another file?

Tags: c++, enums, protocol-buffers

For CPP programming, I have defined a `enum` in a .proto file and I have to use the same enum in another .proto file.

```
//first.proto
package A;
enum foo
{
    COUNTRY_UNKNOWN = 0;
    COUNTRY_INDIA = 1;
}
```

I want to use the `foo` data structure in another .proto file like this:

```
//second.proto
package B;
message bar
{
    foo currentCountry = 1;
}
```

I tried to just import `package A` into second.proto file but it is not able to work. I'm new to protobuf and CPP programming. Please guide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

update like this:

```proto
import 'first.proto';
package B;
message
{
    A.foo currentCountry = 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was trying with import, but didn't use the 'A' prefix with 'foo'. It is working now